# Nested JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript

I would like to make nested JavaScript functions as a prove of concept. I found an example and modified it a little to fit my prove of concent:

```
var t = {
    nestedOne: {
        nest: function() {
            alert('nest');
            this.nestedTwo.nest2();
        },
        nest3: function() {
            alert('nest3');
        },       
        nestedTwo: {
           nest2: function() {
              alert('nest2');
              t.nestedOne.nest3();
           }       
        }
    }
};

t.nestedOne.nest();

// *** Output is nest, nest2 and nest3 ***
```

This works, but I wonder why in nest2, I have to call by `t.nestedOne.nest3`, and not `this.nestedOne.nest3`, similar to how I call from nest2.

Comment: A lot of that is not nested functions, but nested objects.

Comment: For the same reason that you can't use `this.nestedOne.nestedTwo.nest2()` inside your `nest` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all about the context of `this`

The easiest way to explain, is to make a slight change to your code:

```
var t = {
    nestedOne: {
        nest: function() {
            console.log('nest',this);
            this.nestedTwo.nest2();
        },
        nest3: function() {
            console.log('nest3',this);
        },       
        nestedTwo: {
           nest2: function() {
              console.log('nest2',this);
              t.nestedOne.nest3();
           }       
        }
    }
};

t.nestedOne.nest();
```

The output from the above is

> nest Object { nestedTwo={...}, nest=function(), nest3=function()}
>   nest2 Object { nest2=function()}
>   nest3 Object { nestedTwo={...}, nest=function(), nest3=function()}

Note that in the second call, `this` refers to the function, no longer the object.

Now, you can make the following 2 changes

- call `next2` passing in the context of `this`:
      `this.nestedTwo.nest2.call(this);`
- use `this` in `nest2`:
      `this.nest3();`

And all works as expected:

```js
var t = {
    nestedOne: {
        nest: function() {
            console.log('nest',this);
            this.nestedTwo.nest2.call(this);
        },
        nest3: function() {
            console.log('nest3',this);
        },       
        nestedTwo: {
           nest2: function() {
              console.log('nest2',this);
              this.nest3();
           }       
        }
    }
};

t.nestedOne.nest();
```

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see anything in the output window, when I click "Run code snippet".

Comment: Weird, I do - what browser are you on?

Answer (score 0):

The context of a function call is determined by the object on which the function is called, not the left-most object in the path used to get to it.

this:

```
this.nestedTwo.nest2();
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

not this:

```
this.nestedTwo.nest2();
^^^^
```